# Can't run Google Chrome on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, google-chrome

For some reason, no matter how many times I delete (using AppCleaner) and redownload [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html?brand=CHBD&gclid=Cj0KCQjwvabPBRD5ARIsAIwFXBk8zD1-dnWz7dDhl9WidQ1hVswxVm9xrKg3H3Zz5OKaOrz9oe1sM9oaAldAEALw_wcB&dclid=CN6rs_asgNcCFVAONwodC44INQ), I am unable to launch Chrome on my 2017 MacBook Pro running 10.12.6 Sierra.

When I click on the application, it's icon appears momentarily in my Dock and then disappears.  I am using Firefox, downloading directly from Google Chrome's website.

[image]

This is what appears in my system log when I try to run the application:

```
Nov 17 12:29:36 [nameremoved]-mbp ksinstall[94677]: 2017-11-17 12:29:36.137 ksinstall[94677/0xa6f4a1c0] [lvl=2] -[KeystoneInstallTool main] Google Software Update installer started.
Nov 17 12:29:36 [nameremoved]-mbp ksinstall[94677]: 2017-11-17 12:29:36.142 ksinstall[94677/0xa6f4a1c0] [lvl=2] -[KeystoneInstallTool main] Google Software Update installer starting Installation.
Nov 17 12:29:36 [nameremoved]-mbp ksinstall[94677]: 2017-11-17 12:29:36.142 ksinstall[94677/0xa6f4a1c0] [lvl=2] -[KeystoneInstallBackend install] Google Software Update attempting to install.
Nov 17 12:29:36 [nameremoved]-mbp com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.google.Chrome.9556[94673]): Service exited with abnormal code: 21
Nov 17 12:29:36 [nameremoved]-mbp ksinstall[94677]: 2017-11-17 12:29:36.438 ksinstall[94677/0xa6f4a1c0] [lvl=2] +[KSCodeSigningVerification verifyBundle:applicationId:error:] KSCodeSigningVerification verifying code signing for '/Users/[nameremoved]/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle' with the requirement 'anchor apple generic and certificate 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.6] exists and certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.13] exists and certificate leaf[subject.OU]="EQHXZ8M8AV" and (identifier="com.google.Keystone")'
Nov 17 12:29:36 [nameremoved]-mbp ksinstall[94677]: 2017-11-17 12:29:36.475 ksinstall[94677/0xa6f4a1c0] [lvl=2] -[KeystoneInstallBackend shouldInstallWithVersion:error:] Google Software Update found version that is the same or newer: 1.2.9.98.
Nov 17 12:29:36 [nameremoved]-mbp ksinstall[94677]: 2017-11-17 12:29:36.475 ksinstall[94677/0xa6f4a1c0] [lvl=2] -[KeystoneInstallTool main] Google Software Update installer ran successfully.
```

Does anyone know why I might be having this problem? It's making it difficult to test UI code.

Answer (score 2):

If you just deleted the app from the applications folder there may be some remnants hanging out in other places like pref files and other places in the ~/Library/Application Support folder.  Try downloading an app like AppCleaner
http://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/
Drag the app onto its window and it will find the associated files for Chrome.  Then hit the delete button, and then re-download Chrome and try it again.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I should have clarified, I actually have been deleting it with AppCleaner, and the problem has persisted

Comment: Had the same error message, deleted ~/Library/Application Support/Google and tried again.  It worked!